# List Comprehension Function Pointer Python

Tags: python, function, oop, methods, list-comprehension

I have a method (dosomething) that defines an attribute (self.b). Dummy code below:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def dosomething(self, i):
        self.b = 2 * self.a + i
        return self.b ** 2 
testobj = foo()
```

Attribute a can change - so dosomething is called to determine b given the current value of a.

I want to write a list comprehension like the one below. Except, I need to call dosomething for b to change. The dummy code below would just repeat the current value of self.b 20 times.

```
[testobj.b for i in range(20)] # pass i to dosomething then store self.b
```

The quick way is to just return self.b but, the return statement is preoccupied for another value that's much more complicated. If I could return self.b, then the following statement would work:

```
[testobj.dosomething(i) for i in range(20)]
```

Attribute b is just an intermediate value that I want to access. Is there a one liner list comprehension for this situation? I was considering defining a function within the method that returns self.b but, I'm not sure how I would be able to access it properly. So something like foo().dosomething(1).getb() wouldn't work because dosomething(1) evaluates to a number.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def dosomething(self, i):
        self.b = 2 * self.a + i
        def getb():
            return self.b
        return self.b ** 2
```

I guess I should also add that I don't want to be returning a data structure of different values. It would effect much of my code elsewhere.

Comment: Just write a regular loop. It'll be clearer.

Comment: You generally don't want you list-comprehensions to perform side-effects, and in *any* case, the whole **point** of list comprehensions is to provide a *readable* way to expression mapping/filtering operations on iterables. If there is no obvious way, that's a good sign you shouldn't use a list comprehension.

Comment: Have you looked at properties? Because it seems to me that you want `b` to be a property of `foo` and recompute its value every time it's accessed when needed. Or make `a` a property and update `b` whenever `a` changes - which is probably even close to what you need, as your call of `dosomething` will always take the latest values of either into account.

Comment: Note, you can do something horrible, like `[(obj,do_something(i), obj.b)[1] for i in range(10)]` or whatever, but **why**? Just use a for-loop.

Comment: @Grismar I mean, you could use a `property` but this wouldn't really help the OP's problem, which as far as I understand, they want to build a list of the values of `self.b` *after* `self.b` is modified by some method, `obj.do_something(i)`. This is really not a good use-case for list-comprehensions, which should be left to side-effect free operations, but the fundamental problem is that they want `do_something()` to return a particular value, but they want to populate their list with an intermediate value. I've given an example above, but again, it's not a good use for a list comprehension

Comment: Thank you for the responses - I will definitely just use a for loop. Looking back, I'm not sure why I wanted to decrease readability for the sake of saving a few lines

Comment: It seems that your 'dummy example' obfuscates why you'd want something like this in the first place. You have a method that updates the value of an attribute and then returns something based on the value of that attribute - nothing wrong with that, if that makes sense to whoever is using your class. If you need both the new value of `b` and some derived value (like the square), you could just return both and unpack the tuple? The best solution really depends on the needs in the actual use case

Comment: @tryingtocode101 short code is only better if it increases readability, or in some cases if it improves performance. But unless you're playing code golf, never see brevity as a goal by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good use case for list comprehensions.